# 6GB Hidden files on Lumia 520

Tags: lumia-520, storage

Apparently, my phone memory is nearly used up. I estimate about 1GB has been used (camera roll mainly). I downloaded the [Files](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL) app and even that shows 1GB has been used. The question is: Where are the 6GB that seems to be 'hidden' I keep getting a warning that I'm near the 8GB limit....

Comment: What OS version are you using?

Comment: 8.1. What's bothering me is that in Storage Sense I get a breakdown of what's being used. No problem with System taking up 2.7GB or that there's maps, photos and videos taking up 1.5GB (I've deleted about 800Mb of temporary files which has helped) But 'Other' is 700Mb. What the hell is 'Other' and why is it so large??